# Can gnu utils on Mac such as gobjdump parser Linux ELF binary?

Tags: linux, macos, objdump, disassembly

So basically I have some ELF binaries compiled on Linux 32 bit.

And I want to analysis it on my Mac 64 bit.

I am trying to use the gnu utils installed by homebrew such as `gobjdump` and `greadelf`.

However, when I tried to parser the elf binaries using gobjdump, I got this error:

```
gobjdump: hello: File format is ambiguous
gobjdump: Matching formats: elf32-i386-nacl elf32-i386-sol2 elf32-i386-vxworks elf32-i386
```

So my questions are:

1. is it possible to analysis 32 bit Linux compiled ELF binary on MAC using its gnu utils?
2. If possible, how to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Use the `--target=bfdname` option to specify the object code format. The option you probably want is `elf32-i386`.

```
gobjdump -x --target=elf32-i386 hello
```

References: `man gobjdump`